# How to escape literal % in format command in Tcl

Tags: format, tcl

I came across a situation, where I need to use `format` in a string which already contains the literal `%`.
I tried to escape it with backslash. But it didn't help.

```
set a "test %values text here -- %s"; # That last '%s' is what I wanted to replace
set b "dinesh"
puts [ format $a $b ]
```

I tried enclosing the string with braces as well. But no use and getting the following error.

```
--------
bad field specifier "v"
    while executing
"format $a $b "
```

As you can see, it is trying to format like `%v` which is not a valid one.

Comment: This is mentioned in the documentation (look under Mandatory Conversion Type, the last item in the list of type identifiers) but could have been made clearer.

Comment: Yes. I checked it. Thanks Hoodiecrow to point this out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find it anywhere, but you apparently escape the first percentage sign with another percentage sign:

```
set a "test %%values text here -- %s"
set b "dinesh"
puts [ format $a $b ]
# => test %values text here -- dinesh
```

Comment: Can't find it anywhere? It's right there in the conversion types section of the [`format` manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm). The "Details" section explains that while the `format` command is processing a string, each `%` encountered results in a substitution of some type (which this man page calls a "conversion"). This substitution is specified by whatever immediately follows the `%`. In the "Mandatory Conversion Type" section, where it lists various symbols and what type of substitution they cause, the last item listed says `% - No conversion: just insert %`.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Yes.. that's what Hoodiecrow said... Even so, I think it should have been more explicit. The above struck me as putting only `%` alone without anything 'just insert %'. If it were up to me, I would have put an example there.

Comment: Ah, I missed where Hoodiecrow said that (oops, sorry). I completely agree that it could be more clear.